# Update a table with data from another not related table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have three tables A,B and C.
A and B are connected a foreign key A.category_id=B.id , 
A and C have the same number of rows.

A

```
id  category_id value1 value2
1   null        'A'     null
2   null        'B'     null
3   null        'C'     null
4   null        'D'     null
```

B

```
id  category
1   0
2   1
```

C

```
id category
1  0
2  1
3  1
4  0
```

Expected result:

A

```
id  value
1   1
2   2
3   2
4   1
```

I would like to receive updated A table  where category_id will be id from table B based on table C category.

I have tried

```
UPDATE A SET
A.category_id = (
select B.id from  A
    left JOIN  C
      ON A.id = C.id 
    left join  B  on B.category=C.category
    )
WHERE A.id IN (SELECT C FROM C  WHERE A.id = C.id);
```

but then I received ORA-01427 single-row subquery returns more than one row tips

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a correlation clause in the subquery:

```
update A
    set category_id = (select B.id
                       from C join
                            B
                            on B.category = C.category
                       where A.id = C.id
                      )
where exists (select 1 from C where A.id = C.id);
```

To correlated a query, you refer to the outer reference typically in a `where` condition.  You don't repeat the table reference in the `from` clause.

Note that an outer join is unnecessary.  If there is no match, the value will be `NULL`.

Comment: it should be either `where a.id exists (select null from c where a.id = c.id)` or `where a.id in (select c.id from c)`, fwiw. I suspect Gordon was going for the `exists` version, but accidentally put `in`.